# Only one instance of an object at a time

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement, 2d

I'm creating a simple 2D game in Unity. When you press the space bar the game will shoot a ball, and when you press space bar again the ball should "reset". Only one ball should be on the screen at any given time. Here is the conditional logic that I now use to check if a certain `GameObject` is in the scene. I know that `Destroy(cannonBall);` turns it into a `null`, but I can't seem to figure out how I should do this logic differently. Now I get the error that I'm trying to access a deleted object after the conditional logic removes the first ball. (I'm quite new to Unity, and I haven't posted my entire script.)

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && GameObject.Find("Projectile(Clone)")) {
    Destroy(cannonBall);
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && GameObject.Find("Projectile(Clone)") == null )
{
    cannonBall = Instantiate(cannonBall, barell.position, barell.rotation);
    cannonBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(degree * ballVelocity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you **overwrite** the `cannonBall` reference of the prefab with that of the instance!

Then you `Destroy` the instance so the `cannonBall` is now (equal to)`null` and can not be instantiated anymore.

---

=> You should store the instance in a different field!

Then simply `Destroy` the current `cannonBall` if it exists. You already have the reference!

```c#
private GameObject cannonBallInstance;

...

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (cannonBallInstance) 
        {
            Destroy(cannonBallInstance);
        }
        else
        {
            cannonBallInstance= Instantiate(cannonBall, barell.position, barell.rotation);
            cannonBallInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(degree * ballVelocity);
        }
    }
```

---

Actually I wouldn't even destroy and instantiate it all the time but rather create it once and re-use it like

```c#
private Rigidbody2D cannonBallInstance;

...

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (cannonBallInstance) 
        {
            // stop the ball and deactivate it
            cannonBallInstance.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            cannonBallInstance.isKinematic = true;
            cannonBallInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create it once
            // get the component once
            if(!cannonBallInstance) cannonBallInstance = Instantiate(cannonBall, barell.position, barell.rotation).getComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            // activate the ball and allow movement
            cannonBallInstance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            cannonBallInstance.isKinematic = false;

            // assign the transforms and reset the velocity
            cannonBallInstance.position = barell.position;
            cannonBallInstance.rotation = barell.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
            cannonBallInstance.velocity = Vector2.zero;

            cannonBallInstance.AddForce(degree * ballVelocity);
        }
    }
```

---

And then I wouldn't even use `AddForce` for a bullet at all but rather directly assign the target velocity like

```c#
            cannonBallInstance.velocity = degree * ballVelocity;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!